# Xcode Build and Run Succeeds, but Archive Fails with missing framework

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, onesignal

I'm getting crazy. My app is able to build and run successfully, but the archive fails ONLY when I try to do it for Mac Catalyst (for iOS it's working). In specific the error that I'm getting is:

```
error: no such module 'OneSignal' 
import OneSignal
```

The funny fact is, if the OneSignal module was for real missing, it should not let me the app run.

Anyone encountered the same situation before? Please let me know, thanks !

Comment: did you have try this https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/macos-app-sdk-setup    https://onesignal.com/blog/onesignal-supports-mac-catalyst-build/

Comment: Yes, I did! The weird thing is that I'm able to run the app on my Mac but when I want to archive for send the build to App Store, it's complaining that there is no module OneSignal.

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: The funny part is that if you go inside the folder Debug-maccatalyst you will find the app compiled by simulator (it's unsigned) and it works in any mac with OneSignal working. Remember that for open the app in other Mac you have to do it the first time with right-click, open, and authorize the app for run.

Comment: do you find solution? answer please